# Nuxt content Shiki plugin returns : ERROR /home not found

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I'm trying to use syntax highlighter with [@nuxt/content](https://content.nuxtjs.org) and [Shiki](https://content.nuxtjs.org/snippets/#custom-highlighter).

After installing the shiki package in my `nuxt.config.js` project file.

```js
import shiki from 'shiki'

...

export default {
  modules: ['@nuxt/content'],

  content: {
    markdown: {
      async highlighter() {
        const highlighter = await shiki.getHighlighter({
          theme: 'nord'
        })
        return (rawCode, lang) => {
          return highlighter.codeToHtml(rawCode, lang)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got

```js
Error
/home not found
```

But when I remove the `highlighter` method in the content, everything works fine. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the import and `await shiki`, use the require method of using it.

```js
  content: {
    markdown: {
      async highlighter () {
        const highlighter = await require('shiki').getHighlighter({
          theme: 'github-dark'
        })

        return (rawCode, lang) => {
          return highlighter.codeToHtml(rawCode, lang)
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

This is what I did to get it working.

An alternative solution to the above that also works would be:

```js
import { getHighlighter } from 'shiki';

// ...

  content: {
    markdown: {
      async highlighter () {
        const highlighter = await getHighlighter({
          theme: 'github-dark'
        })

        return (rawCode, lang) => {
          return highlighter.codeToHtml(rawCode, lang)
        }
      }
    }
  },
```